# How to access different properties in array of objects - each object has different keys

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried the below 2 options but both are not working.

**JSON**

```
{
   "Properties": [
                {
                    "Type": "LEI"
                },
                {
                    "Country": "DE"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Credit Institution"
                }
            ]
}
```

**Angular Typescript**

Option #1

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-entity>
  <tr>
    <td>{{entity.Properties[Type]}}</td>
    <td>{{entity.Properties[Country]}}</td>
    <td>{{entity.Properties[Name]}}</td>
  </tr>
 </ng-template>
```

Option #2

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-entity>
  <tr>
    <td>{{entity.Properties.Type}}</td>
    <td>{{entity.Properties.Country}}</td>
    <td>{{entity.Properties.Name}}</td>
  </tr>
 </ng-template>
```

**Update:-**

**My real JSON**

```
    {
    "_id": "5bcb2dbfe8ffdd1bd0913825",
    "_entitykey": "CRD_CRE_INS.CRDINSLEICODE",
    "_validfrom": "2018-10-20T13:31:35.040Z",
    "_validto": "2100-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "_datahash": "84f28a3fed7d3a1e5e2b21e5bc91e8a1",
    "_payload": {
        "CA_OwnerID": "EU_ECB",
        "EntityCode": "CRDINSLEICODE",
        "EntityType": "CRD_CRE_INS",
        "Properties": [{
                "EEA_DEP_GUA_SCH": [
                    "IS_TIF",
                    "GB_FSCS"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ENT_AU": [
                    "2017-09-05",
                    "2018-10-05",
                    "2019-01-01"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ENT_COD_TYP": "LEI"
            },
            {
                "ENT_COU_RES": "DE"
            },
            {
                "ENT_NAM": "Credit Institution In Germany"
            },
            {
                "ENT_NAT_REF_COD": "REFCODE12342"
            },
            {
                "ENT_TOW_CIT_RES": "GERMAN TOWN1243"
            },
            {
                "INT_CAP_REQ_UND_ART_12": "ART_12_1_CRD"
            },
            {
                "TYP_UND_ACC_CRR_ART_27": "ART_27_1_A1_CRR"
            },
            {
                "IS_HID_NOT_PUB": "0"
            }
        ],
        "Services": [{
                "DE": [
                    "PS_010",
                    "PS_020",
                    "PS_03A",
                    "PS_03B"
                ]
            },
            {
                "GR": [
                    "PS_010",
                    "PS_020"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note on naming: You're not "parsing" by key; you're accessing by key. Also, by the time it gets to your template, it's not JSON; it's just an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to map the properties into a single structure and then you can access the properties as you want to.

The resulting structure would look like the following:

```
{
  "Type": "LEI",
  "Country": "DE",
  "Name": "Credit Institution"
}
```

So you will be accessing a single object instead of an array of objects with different properties, like so:

```js
var entity = {
   "Properties": ([
      {
          "Type": "LEI"
      },
      {
          "Country": "DE"
      },
      {
          "Name": "Credit Institution"
      }
  ]).reduce((res, curr) => Object.assign(res, curr), {})
}

console.log(entity.Properties)
```

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-entity>
  <tr>
    <td>{{entity.Properties.Type}}</td>
    <td>{{entity.Properties.Country}}</td>
    <td>{{entity.Properties.Name}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Or, if you want to show all properties, you can do so dynamically, like so:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-entity>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let key of entity.Properties">{{entity.Properties[key]}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample application to bind property dynamically on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hg3qkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Here is the component code.

```js
data = {
   "Properties": [
                {
                    "Type": "LEI"
                },
                {
                    "Country": "DE"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Credit Institution"
                }
            ]
}

columns:string[] = [];
ngOnInit(){
  for(let row of this.data.Properties){
    for(var columnName in row){
      this.columns.push(columnName)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Html Code.

```js
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data.Properties; let i = index">
    <td >{{row[columns[i]]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

First you need to create a columns array and bind that in the html.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: This is working under the assumption that the OP wants the columns in the same order as the data is coming back, or that the data is coming back in the correct order and no other properties are included.

Comment: this is working as expected. please let me know if you see any issue. if you want order then it should be managed from server.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work for the OP's stripped down example, all I said was it was working under the assumption that the data returned will be in exactly the right format for the UI. That can be a lofty assumption in many cases, especially if your data is coming from a third-party API.

Comment: then please explain your cases,

Comment: See the OP's updated question showing the real JSON data returned - that demonstrates my point exactly.

Comment: dynamically this can be possible. but which field you want to show on ui in which format. please explain. so that I can help you out.

Comment: @AjayOjha Thanks all fields mate